python lambda function works in colab but not in jupyter for loop
Code doesn't work as intended in jupyter notebook and I have just run the update request but much of my environment was at the latest version already (so don't think it is a version) here is the code (that is suppose to remove spaces and commas from strings in the specific column);
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   row['Actors'] = [x.lower().replace(' ','') for x in row['Actors']]
   row['Director'] = ''.join(row['Director']).lower()

e.g. [Tim Robbins,  Morgan Freeman,  Bob Gunton]' goes to'[timrobbins, morganfreeman, bobgunton] jupyter executes the code with no errors reported but doesn't change the data. Colab runs perfect the first time.
The same is needed for director column however here there is only one name ;
e.g. [Frank, Darabont] goes to frankdarabont (or should!)
I want to convert objects like director from a first name, last name to a joined firstnamelastname, similarly the actors, convert their full names into a single string (one for each actor)
Here is the dataframe.


Can you show all of the relevant code? Right now, there's no way this wouldn't create the behavior you describe, and I'm running it in a jupyter notebook

1- why would you use iterrows for such a task? (you shouldn't) 2- you should provide a [mre] of the data

It is probably the versions of Pandas in the two environments. The latest Pandas is much more strict and a lot of the stuff it has been warning about being deprecated in the past is now deprecated and not going to give any warning.

I think you're looking for this:
df['Actors'] = df['Actors'].str.lower().str.replace(r'(?<!,)\s', '', regex=True)
df['Director'] = df['Director'].str.lower().str.replace(r'\s', '', regex=True)

The result:


Great, thanks, can I keep the first three names in the 'Actors' column and drop the rest easily?

Please don't include code as an image. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3581217

@Bart the code I didn't include as an image just the result.

@ericclapp yes, you can. Do this: df['Actors'] = df['Actors'].str.lower().str.split(',').str[:3].astype(str).str[1:-1].str.replace("'", "").str.replace(r'(?<!,)\s', '', regex=True)

From that meta post: _"You should not post code (or errors/exceptions, logs, configuration, project files, or anything else that is represented in textual form) as an image because...".
